# What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-accounts, faq-proposed, account-destruction

Prompted by *[Generic-ize a user's name when their account is destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88836/generic-ize-a-users-name-when-their-account-is-destroyed)*, it appears there are two methods of disabling user accounts permanently:  deleting and "destroying"

- What are the differences between deleting and destroying a user?
- What determines which method is used?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Other proposed types of terminal account disposition: annihilate, expurgate, overwrite, deracinate, extirpate, flush, rm, mv to /dev/null, multiply by zero, divide by aleph-null, calculate the limit as Posts->Inanity of f(User), stack overflow of downvotes (more downvotes than they can handle), migrate to Davy Jones' Locker.SE, exile to Paradise, California, licked to death by kittens.

Comment: I thought "deleted" users were ones who had been self- or moderator-removed, whereas "destroyed" users were ones who had been caught on film asking Ben Shapiro a question on a school campus.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

"Deleted" users have their display name denormalized, their account deleted, and all of their *negatively-scored* posts deleted (except on meta sites and open questions with one or more positively-scored answers). Anything not deleted is retained with their "ghost" user. This is primarily for scenarios like a user requesting their account be deleted, or multiple suspensions have not helped with a user's conduct.

"Destroyed" users have all that, but also have all of their posts and comments deleted. It is intended for things like spammers, where we just want them to be gone. A user must have less than 500 reputation in order to be destroyed ([ignoring suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105953/377214) which set reputation to 1). Given that, it's up to the moderator to simply select "destroy" from the mod menu.

Comment: Just an interesting corner case here: if you have an account on A.SE and an account on B.SE, delete the account on B.SE and then have one of your A.SE posts migrated to B.SE, the migrated post shows your non-ghost name.

Comment: If a destroyed user has *all* their posts deleted, how can you even *tell* if their name is "blanketed"?

Comment: @Gnemlock deleted posts are visible to high reputation users.