# If I request Account deletion, negatively rated questions of mine will get auto-deleted even if there is highly voted answers?

Tags: support

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user/88996#88996) answer

> "Deleted" users have their display name denormalized, their account deleted, and all of their ***negatively rated posts will be deleted***. Anything with a score of 0 or higher is retained with their "ghost" user. This is primarily for scenarios like a user requesting their account for deletion, and it has some degree of reversibility.

If I request Account deletion, negatively rated questions of mine will get auto-deleted even if there is highly voted answers?

Comment: Is this hypothetical or are you planning on deleting your account?

Comment: @alex, I am a bit serious on this case. But that will depend on correct answer on this question and if moderators stick to reject my question delete request.

Comment: Why leave? I wanted to leave about a year ago, but I decided to just not participate for a while (a month) and see what happens. In the end, I couldn't sit away. Don't do things in a rush, just because you're angry right now; cool down and think it through.

Comment: @alex, it's really annoying that you get unwanted comments and answers on questions that you can't delete ....

Comment: Ignore them; do they really bother you that much? Or ask for the questions to be disassociated with your account, if possible. It's a less extreme solution.

Comment: @alex, if you keep getting answers or comments, you can't ignored (at least me)

Comment: If you're worried about notifications on answers, why not simply delete that answer? Why do you have to resort to deleting your entire account? This seems like a bit of a drastic step...

Comment: @Cody, because it is a question, I cannot delete it myself.

Comment: @Delete: Then ask for deletion of the question please! (And sorry, I left a comment at that question, too.)

Comment: @Hendrik, my delete request got rejected - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91315/why-was-my-question-delete-request-rejected

Comment: @YOU: Hmm. At least it's anonymized. But there are still lots of comments of YOU (and responses to those) hanging around. Maybe it would suffice if a moderator deletes those comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account deletions are kind of a rare case, so this isn't particularly common.

But yes -- in a normal account delete:

- questions or answers with a score of -1 or lower are deleted
- questions or answers with a score of 0 or better are retained

Comment: This does not seem like an ideal situation, if there well-rated answers for a negatively-rated question... seems like it would be better to let humans decide in that case?