# "Destroy" suspended accounts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, moderator-tools

Once accounts reach a certain reputation threshold, the account can no longer be destroyed by the moderator.

However, that restriction seems to be circumventable by first suspending the user (which sets the user rep to 1)? At least in the moderator dialogue box, after a high-rep user is suspended, the "destroy" radio button which usually is greyed out becomes available for selection again.

Note that I didn't test whether the button would actually work: I don't want to destroy someone's account just "in the name of science" `;-p`!

Comment: Obviously, the proper course of action here is to destroy *your own* account. *For Science!*

Comment: Or, if you don't like taking risks like that, I think this would be a noble use of a sock account.

Comment: @PeterOfTheCorn yeah but that would require reaching the reputation threshold, which isn't really worth the effort to test something like this.

Comment: @Shog9 But if he first suspends himself, then can he still use the destroy?

Comment: Try this with Jon Skeet's account; see if he gets the joke :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the next build we'll check the *actual* rep on suspended users before allowing a destroy.

If they do have over 500 rep (even though showing 1) it'll blow up the same as trying to destroy any other > 500 rep user.