# User is suspended network-wide, except not really

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, network-wide-suspension

A user has been active on one of the sites recently, even though they're concurrent suspended ***network-wide*** on the rest of the network.

How is this possible, and is it possible to evade a network suspension on only one site?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They were unsuspended manually by a moderator on that site.

This is... probably intentional? The fact that something like this is possible in the first place may or may not be harmful, depending on the user and the site in question.

In the specific case a moderator was apparently testing if this was possible.

We may revisit network suspensions to lock them down further, but honestly, I'm not too worried about it. It's rare for a "real" user to get suspended network-wide, and if a particular community still feels they're welcome there... fine.

Comment: @peterh See [Shog's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323442).