# How long should I wait for Contact Support to respond?

Tags: support, chat, account-suspension, contact

I have written only twice to Contact Support in the 3 years, 4 months I have joined Stack Exchange. The first reply came within three days, it was an enquiry about a third party. I was satisfied by the response, and decided to drop the matter. But I am still waiting for a reply to my second enquiry. I think it has been over a week now. This time I was asking about myself.

I am currently serving a year long suspension on English Language & Usage for breaking the rules. I am not disputing the fact I broke the rules.

In order to avoid speculation, I will state what the offenses were. I opened two new accounts while serving the first (24 Aug '16) and second suspension (Aug 31 '16). While I was using my new second account, I gained a fair bit of rep, and I upvoted one of my answers on the suspended account.  That was wrong, and I deeply regret doing that.

The second suspension was for circumventing the first suspension, there was no mention whatsoever about sockpuppets. In my reply to the second suspension, I TOLD the mods I had upvoted an answer belonging to the suspended account, and that I accepted their verdict. Not long after, I willfully  opened a third, and illegal,  account. That little act of rebellion cost me a year's suspension.

To be absolutely clear, I am not asking for the suspension to be lifted, I accept their verdict. But there are a number of issues which have not been clarified, and I would appreciate some answers, a discussion, a meeting of minds, call it what you will.

Obviously, I cannot ask over at EL&U meta because I am banned from there. It is pointless my asking on English Language Learners meta because they would not understand the situation, and the reason(s) why I flouted the rules.

I [cannot use chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean/285227#285227) on EL&U, and recently I discovered to my chagrin, neither in ELL. The main site is EL&U which means chat at ELL is off bounds.

In fact one of queries to CS specifically mentioned this issue.

> **EDIT**
>   I have since learned that there is only one main (parent) site, which is Stack Exchange, and all the other SE sites are sister sites. As a result, I am to all intents and purposes, banned from using chat in all eight communities which I am a member of.

In addition,  the mods on EL&U have chosen not reply to my message, when they notified me that I was be suspended for a year on September 7th. But I have yet to receive any official response to my message dated 10th September. If they had done so, I would have enquired about the two or three issues I brought to CS's attention.

Finally, I have never acted like a ‘jerk’ in the 3 years and  4 months I have been a member. But I suppose you could say my opening two new accounts was ‘jerkish’  behaviour. So be it.

In conclusion, how long should I wait before Contact Support replies?

---

**UPDATE**

On 30 Sep I received an email of acknowledgement from Contact Support. But I have yet to hear any news from them about my queries. Albeit I have since discovered the reason why I cannot use chat anywhere, with the sole exception of Stackoverflow and SE meta.

I really don't know how to interpret this prolonged silence. But considering the amount of time that has lapsed, my hope is, at the very least, I won't receive a one-line message informing me that they found no support for my reservations.

Comment: Opening another account to get around a ban was what you did wrong, not voting for your own answer (that just makes it worse). You say you can't bring up your queries on ELU or ELL meta, can't you bring hem up here?

Comment: @Cai Well if absolutely necessary, but it might cost me a suspension. The issue is personal.

Comment: If the site moderators decided you are not welcome on the site any more, Stack Exchange team/staff can't really help you. They will not, and should not, force the moderators to do something against their will. That said, on rare cases emails do get lost, so you can try and ping a CM directly either via email (many CM's publish their emails on their profiles) or in chat, e.g. Tavern. (One ping, either way - no response will probably mean they got nothing to say.)

Comment: And as for "acting like a jerk", that's not true. Bypassing suspension by opening new accounts is exactly like escaping from prison. Nothing more, nothing less. You can enjoy the freedom while it lasts, but if you get caught, expect more time in prison, and better security.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, does that include my email to Contact Support? Could I least get a copy back of the email I wrote? Can I write and ask them for that? I didn't think that I wouldn't get a reply from them.

Comment: Most email clients (well, all I know of, but there are surely others) do save a copy of all the emails you send. For example, in gmail you can find them in "Sent Mail" folder. If your email client does not have such a copy or you deleted it, you can ask for a copy.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you for your patience but the "email" I sent to CS was written in the open window box. I have no record of it in my "sent mail".  I did not delete it. Are you saying that CS might never respond? I call it an email, but it was a letter written in a box "Please describe your problem*. I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought you wrote them directly, so you mean you used the "contact us" form. In such a case you're right, there's no copy. But if they will reply,  you'll see your message quoted below the reply. And you can still ask for a copy, though I doubt they'll just send you your copy without any response - it would be either both, or nothing. Good luck!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I expressed myself poorly. My question remains, how long should I wait before receiving a reply, and hence a copy of the original message I sent. "or nothing"?? So I might never get a response. Oh...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no fixed time range. One week is reasonable enough though, my advice is writing email directly to team@stackexchange.com and gently asking if they got your previous request, giving your nick and profile URL on the site where you sent the "contact us" form from.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Can I mention your name and your advice? Thank you so much for responding by the way. At last, I feel I am speaking to someone with authority, someone who is objective.

Comment: I will wait another day or two before emailing Contact Support. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Go ahead, I stand behind my advice (but again, don't send more than one email) - and I'm afraid I got no real authority here, by all means I'm in the same level/position as you. Ordinary user.

Comment: Yes, that may well be so, likewise the mods on EL&U are ordinary users, but you replied.

Comment: I have a problem with the jail analogy, which seems very neat and tidy, and I realised what it is. Shouldn't defendants be able to defend themselves before being sentenced?

Comment: Are you referring to your reply to the year-long suspension message, or to an email you sent to the team@stackexchange.com?

Comment: Your request was assigned to someone for review on Wednesday. As Monica explains, complicated matters do take a bit more time to look at, but it is still there and hasn't been ignored. Also keep in mind that most of us do not look through or think about these requests over the weekend.

Comment: @animuson usually there is automated response like "We got your request and will handle it shortly" - any reason SE doesn't have such a response?

Comment: @ShadowWizard They cause a lot of problems that we don't want to deal with. The email field is free form - you can type anything you want there, which opens the door to a) people entering fake emails and us getting a ton of bounceback notifications to sift through and b) people entering other users' emails and annoying them with "your message was received" emails. Among other things, we decided that an automated response upon receipt just wasn't worth the minimal benefit it gives to users.

Comment: @Mari-LouA as for defending yourself, this should be possible via the first warning one should get, before being suspended. I can't tell for sure since I never was part of this (neither receiving side nor giving side) but from what I've seen over the years, before suspending a user, especially a veteran user, a moderator sends a private message, and the user can then reply to this message. That's the equivalent for defending yourself, then if this doesn't help, SE staff is the high court, which can be contacted via the form or direct email.

Comment: @animuson fair enough, so what about an email when the request is being assigned? (i.e. confirmed to be actual valid request from actual user)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sounds like something we could easily do. I'll bring it up at our next meeting.

Comment: @animuson awesome, thanks. Want me to start a feature request here, or leave it away from the spotlights?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Up to now I've received an acknowledgement that my request was received, then (a week later) I asked for a copy of the said request, which I obtained, and.... nothing more. Is this normal? Three weeks and counting before hearing what the team actually has to say? Is the length of time a sign in my favour? Does it mean that my main dispute is being taken seriously? Or, are they hoping I'm going to "forget" and drop the matter?

Comment: Because if, if,  I'm right, and my main contestation is being taken seriously, there should have been no first suspension to begin with.

Comment: @Mari-LouA sorry for delay, had to think about it for a while. My conclusion is that we can't really know what's going on on their side. Maybe your request has been "lost" somehow, maybe the one it's assigned to still trying to figure how to handle it. We can't, and better not speculate, what's really going on. You can try ping  animuson again to ask for an update. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, the team has definitely received my request, they sent me a copy when I asked. I wanted to have a look at it to see if I bypassed anything major, but I hadn't. Thanks for replying in any case.

Comment: No doubt they received, but I mean maybe the one it was assigned to passed it to somebody else, who did not get it.

Comment: @animuson could you please enquire on the status of my request? I still have not received an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's on Tim Post's plate at this point. He likes to be thorough and I can't guarantee when you'll get a response, but rest assured you'll get a detailed response from someone who will have spent a lot of time looking into this.

Comment: @animuson thank you for taking the time to tell me. I suppose I'll have to wait some more.

Comment: @Mari-LouA for what it's worth, I vouch for Tim Post being fair and just. Can't promise he'll do what you want/expect, but surely it will be after lots of thought, and thinking about Stack Exchange above all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard just to let you know how things are progressing at my end. After my third email last night,  Mr Tim Post has  promised  I will receive an answer within 24 hours.  At this point in time, I don't hold out much hope. Too many weeks have slipped by, I might as well suck it up as they say in the States. To say I am hugely disappointed by Tim Post's solicited tardy response is a gross understatement.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Mari. Can't defend Tim or SE here, not enough details about the inner workings of this. Hope that you will get a proper response soon, though no doubt it is way too late.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think you know by now, I seem to recall a message of yours but I couldn't respond b/c the computer was sick. The suspension has been lifted, patience paid off in the end, and I'd like to thank Tim Post for taking an interest in my case.

Comment: Cheers, glad to hear that!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Response time varies a lot, based on:

- How complicated the situation is.
- Whether anybody can handle it or it requires specific expertise.  (For example, only some team members can make database modifications.)
- Load.

I've had responses in a day or two, and I've had issues that took a couple weeks to resolve.  If your request was very specialized or complicated, I'd give it a little more time before worrying.  If it was routine and you're concerned that it just might have gotten lost, then (as Shadow Wizard suggested in comments), you can send email to team@stackexhange.com to inquire.  It will probably help if you tell them on which site you submitted the support request.