# Can a user in timed suspension edit their own posts?

Tags: support, edits, account-suspension

I did find [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/157730), which says that

> When an account is suspended [...] The account holder will be unable to ask, answer, comment, use any of their privileges, accept an answer, or award a bounty.

However, unlike editing others' posts, *editing a post of your own isn't a privilege that in any way depends on reputation.*

*Specifically,* is a user who is in [timed suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) able to *edit their existing posts* on the site where their account has been placed in timed suspension?

Comment: allowing suspended users to do *anything* would be a serious loophole. Any action can be abused, and we don't want the situation where deleting the entire account is the only option that mods have to stop abuse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, suspended users cannot do *anything* on-site. They can literally only view pages.

Comment: But you could still edit anonymously, right? Or is there something in place to prevent that too? (Apart from the review system that processes all anonymous edits.)

Comment: @Laurel major edit will likely not pass, just writing "I am the author" in the edit summary won't make the reviewers believe it. They will see attempt to radically change a post by unknown person.

Comment: They can also reply to moderator messages.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the reason a suspended user cannot edit their posts is to prevent the possibility that they may seek to vandalize them.

Comment: Or bump them so they will get upvoted in order get back reputation lost from sockpuppet deletion.