# Regarding the suspension of my account

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I am using this account. Today morning I have answered a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Suddenly my reputation dropped down. What is the reason for this issue? I am totally disappointed.

This week I was scoring nearly 500+ reputations. I lost everything.

**Edit**:
I got a mail like below.

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your Mathematics Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://math.stackexchange.com/users/253506/avinash-n
>
> Due to clear signs of falsified accounts being used to artificially
>   inflate your reputation, your account has been temporarily suspended
>   for 7 days.
>
> It is not fair to other users of Mathematics Stack Exchange to allow
>   users to gain reputation through sockpuppets.
>
> The offending accounts have been removed and the votes invalidated.
>   Please refrain from this behavior in the future.
>
> Regards, Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Comment: usually when an account is suspended you are notified by the mods. Did you not receive any message, any explanation?

Comment: [**When an account is suspended** 
The account will receive a private moderator message, explaining the exact details of the suspension and a box to contact moderators.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: OK, I visited your profile page and it clearly says **‘This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 7 days’** If you feel there has been a mistake contact the mod team or [contact support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact). The link is found at the bottom of this page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am using mobile application. It doesn't show anything.

Comment: The key point is this: Did you not receive a message from the mods informing you on the suspension? Messages are always notified regardless of which platform you're on.

Comment: Delete my question, please.

Comment: I don't know why I was notified in my inbox, but your best bet of deleting this question is asking Glorfindel to delete their answer, if they do–which would be a kind gesture–then you can delete your post by clicking on the delete tab. However, questions with answers that have been upvoted cannot be deleted by their owners. Or visit chat and ask someone there what else you could do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA off topic, but you got notified because you're the sole commenter other than the OP, so OP's comment will automatically notify you even without @-ping (and it won't be in the future since I participated in this thread)

Answer (score 14):

You've been [suspended for voting irregularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/253506/avinash-n); you've permanently lost [205 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/253506/avinash-n?tab=reputation) which was deemed to be gained in a forbidden way (i.e. other users upvoting your posts because they know you or they *are* you). The other reputation you had will be restored after the suspension period ends.

Comment: IOW a sockpuppet

Comment: Could be; details like that usually aren't shared, even in the moderator message, to not make it easier to escape detection the next time.