# Is there a way to appeal decisions made by the Stack Overflow Support Team team members?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team

I made a support request with the Stack Overflow Support Team on May 14th, 2019.  The team member responded to my request the next day.

I believed that the course of action proposed by the team member was inappropriate (i.e., self-removal of my account).  I requested to appeal the decision to a supervisor.  The team member responded with a terse, "You cannot. You have been provided your options already."

I have since attempted to appeal the decision by submitting a new ticket, but that resulted in no response.

Is there a way we can effectively appeal a team member's decision?

Comment: There is nothing we, as community can do. We don't have the details nor insight how staff procedures are executed. From a practical point of view I think it is fine that there is no appeal once you reached out to SE staff. We can't keep appealing until you reached an outcome you like.

Comment: An appeal process is a common practice in many contexts, for obvious reasons.  The question asked about how to effectively *appeal* the decision made by a team member.  It didn't indicate that an unlimited number of appeals were desired - which would be senseless.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with an appeal.  The problem here is that you're appealing to the wrong people; we're the community, not the staff at SE, and you've provided zero details as to your issue.  Other than talking to support, there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: I would assume *You have been provided your options already* leave no room for an other outcome. An appeal would be senseless. I don't agree an appeal practice is needed for how a support ticket is handled. Unless you have something that you want to bring to court but then you let your lawyer do the talking.

Comment: Posting a question on meta is a method of getting the attention of someone in SE outside the support team though @fbueckert, which clicking the contact us link may not do.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Except there's already *been* a response.  Options have been provided, and without more details, there's nothing we can help with.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316631/what-can-i-do-to-lift-or-reduce-a-suspension

Comment: @adpatter I was not trying to emphasize the law analogy, more the implication that some users want other users to get mired in strings of appeals for free.  No!!

Comment: @MartinJames You're conflating again.

Comment: Its worth taking into account SE is *pretty small* and the folks upstairs already probably already know.  Unless there's a bunch of support folks they have hidden away that I'm not aware of (and as a avoid user, I doubt so) - there's about 2 people who handle tickets, and under a dozen community team folks in total.

Answer (score 9):

Meta - either Meta Stack Exchange or the per-site meta if this relates to a specific site - is a place where you can explain your situation and get input from other users. This includes asking for help understanding why a  support request may have been handled a certain way.

If you're willing to explain your situation on meta, feel free to do so but do your best to convey the information as openly and neutrally as you can without accusations of wrongdoing. Also know that when you ask publicly, your response will also be public, whether that's from users or staff.

Our support staff is great and I trust them. Sometimes, though, our policies can be confusing so getting help understanding them is something many of our meta regulars are often willing to do. But be aware that they won't have as much information as our support staff do and may be unable to fully explain the decision.

Comment: Just checking: are there limits on which topics will be responded to by SE staff, if at all? I mean, are we now open on MSE to settle all kind of disputes that were ultimately handled by staff? Some stuff can't be appealed, right?

Comment: The focus of my answer is on using meta to help users understand the decision, not really changing it. Meta has always been for that. I'm pretty sure that we've always allowed people to come here with complaints about how we decided something... they just don't generally go well.

Comment: Fair enough. The *they don't go well* is a bit of an understatement ;)