# What recourse does a (mistakenly?) deleted spam account have?

Tags: discussion, spam, account-suspension, moderator-messages

There is of course a specific post that prompted this, but I'm not going to link it unless necessary.

Anyway, to the point; under the idea that a user's account is destroyed because it was labeled a spam account, is there any recourse for the user, aside from the contact page linked to from the bottom of the site?  When a user is suspended, they are sent a moderator message they can reply (once) to, and then they cannot reply again until a [diamond] moderator or CM responds.

However, if an automatic one year suspension is applied to an account that was labeled as being a spammer after it is recreated after being destroyed, is there a moderator message sent to that account that the account holder can reply to, or is it without a message?

Thus, is account holder that was (possibly) wrongly accused of being a spammer out of luck until they ask a question and someone stumbles on said question on Meta.SE? (I am aware that site-specific questions on Meta.SE are off topic.)

On the assumption that there is no moderator message for the auto-suspension on a recreated deleted account, what recourse is there for a user under that suspension?

If the contact link at the bottom of this or any other site in the SE network is the only recourse for a user suspended under these circumstances, can this information be added to the official FAQ regarding suspensions?  If not, why not?

Comment: @Makyen I'd say yes and no.  Yes: It looks like roughly the same question.  No: There's no official response, or answer that describes the best course of action.

Comment: What requirement do you have for an "official response"? And do you think you would get one here?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying Any staff member or a diamond mod weighing in.  That said, I don't have high hopes that either would happen.

Comment: The answer does describe the best/only course of action: ["Contacting staff is the only appeal option"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355538/271271). I'm not saying that there couldn't be a more complete answer, but merely that the answer does provide the minimal information. There is more information scattered around about this specific situation, so a more comprehensive answer would be possible. But, the proposed duplicate, within both the question and answer, does answer all questions which are contained in the question here.

Comment: @Daedalus, but Makyen *is* a diamond mod.

Comment: "a diamond mod weighing in" I see no less than 4 diamond moderators who weighed in on the linked post, in the comments at least. As a diamond moderator myself on several sites, I'd say the same thing: The suspended user needs to contact staff.

Comment: @Laurel I quick scanned comments; I didn't notice the usernames in question.  That said, comments should never be the place to look for concrete information that should be in an answer.

Comment: That *is* the answer given to the other post

Comment: @Laurel It is, yes, but unless I am mistaken, it does not appear that Luuklag is a moderator on any site.  It seems the answer itself is an FAQ proposition, but until it is added to said FAQ, it may not hold weight in other users' minds, especially with how hard it is to find said information.  Anyway, in regards to the FAQ itself, I added another question to this one, even as I realize at this point that I'd likely need to tag this with `faq-proposed` or something.  However, this is not a post that is fit to be included in an FAQ at this time, so that's why I didn't do so yet.

Comment: @markalex While that is true, it is my(perhaps wrong) belief that there should be a central way to find this information, without having to dig through ephemeral comments.

Comment: @Daedalus, your belief is correct. My comment was only related to current question, where mod itself proposed a duplicate. Regarding hope for answer in linked question to be more official, while it'd probably be ideal, I wouldn't wage much hope on this. Answer provided by community seems reasonable and consistent with information on the topic elsewhere: no apparent reason to for an employees or a mod to rewrite the same answer.

Comment: @Daedalus, one more avenue to get more authoritative answer, is to start a bounty. I'm not sure how effective this might be, especially at this time of the year, but maybe you will be lucky to find a mod who is "farming" reputation at MSE =)

Comment: Here's a [staff comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371933/could-we-have-longer-automatic-suspensions-for-destroyed-profiles-and-better-co#comment1279154_383399) saying that the contact form is the only way to appeal.

Comment: Also, to note: the target question's comments were all posted when the auto suspension period was only 14 days.