# My account has been suspended and I'm not sure how to contact moderators to appeal

Tags: support, account-suspension

I had written "I love spamming" in the answer section of one the questions, but I have deleted it very soon after I had written it. I did it because I was bored and now I realize the mistake. I have my exams in the next week and I have been blocked for 10 days on the *[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site. I feel really guilty of spamming and I am sorry.

In comments, they have asked me contact the moderators from the notification I get regarding my suspension, but I have checked them. I haven't got any notification. I am reposting this question, because I have done this mistake due to my ignorance. Also, I am not a new contributor.

Is there any way I could reverse it? How can I contact the mods so that I could apologize

I am extremely sorry for violating the rules of stack exchange

Comment: I cleaned up a the comments about rate-limiting (not relevant) and suspension messages. This is a case of a user recreating a profile previously destroyed for spamming, which applies an automatic 14 day suspension upon recreation and means there won't be a moderator message to reply to.

Comment: If you really think that was unwarranted because you never wrote spam or nonsense on that site, follow the guidance in the answer below and use the Contact link. But given how the remainder is only 10 days, just dealing with the consequences of your own actions might be less of a waste of time as I don't know if your contact ticket will be handled quickly enough, especially not with a weekend coming up...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are unable to contact your site moderation team because you can't find a message from the mod team about your suspension, you can use the "[Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link at the bottom of every page on Stack Exchange and select the "Appeal a suspension" reason. Read the information provided carefully before submitting the form.

That link contacts the company's Community Team, and they are responsible for all the communities on Stack Exchange, so you should always try to get in touch with your local mod team first.

The reason there was no moderator message associated with the author's suspension is because it was deleted as a spam account. See the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278803/273494) of the feature request post [Automatically suspend accounts recreated after a moderator deleted the original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277230/273494) for more explanation of how that works.

Comment: Also what is link to moderator message if available?

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding the instructions on the contact form, just fill it out to the best of your ability. You may want to include a link to this meta post.

Comment: May I also know why am I getting soo many downvotes is there something wrong with my question? I am sorry if it does

Comment: I don't know why some people chose to downvote. They might feel like you should have searched before asking. You might have found [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/273494) or  [What can I do to lift or reduce a suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316631/what-can-i-do-to-lift-or-reduce-a-suspension). Questions about how to get a suspension lifted on a specific site get asked a lot here even though those questions are off-topic and it is annoying to some people.

Comment: I am sorry should I delete this question now?

Comment: (chemistry mod here.) I can't answer this question, but after a bit of investigation, it turns out that their original profile on Chemistry was destroyed for spamming. Now they re-created their Chemistry site profile and the suspension was automatically applied to the new one, hence the lack of a message.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks for following up.  The moral of the story: Don't pretend to be a spammer, even as a joke, unless you're willing to be mistaken for one :)