# Highly upvoted but has 1 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, answers

I searched for an answer using the title of this question on Meta.Workplace and on Meta.SE but nothing came up.

[This answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/124717/66194) has been upvoted *a lot*.

But the person that wrote the initial answer only has 1 reputation.

How?

Comment: They're suspended, see [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/398063)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens when an account is suspended.

If you look at their profile, it shows:

[image]

After the suspension ends, their reputation should recalculate and no longer show as 1.