# Feature request: add option to suspend users indefinitely, similar to Mediawiki sites

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension

On Mediawiki-based websites like Wikimedia sites (and a lot of others), there is a option to block users indefinitely, instead of temporarily.
This will be useful to ban users that violate Stack Exchange's site rules, and will be a replacement to long (5+ year) blocks if needed.

Also add an option to block the user's IP address to prevent new account registrations from the same person.

Comment: There are users suspended for 99 years. Won't this have the same effect?

Comment: My thread already has downvotes, why many people don't support my feature request? Oh, yeah, I didn't see this comment, but it will be better to block indefinitely instead to prevent some users from being surprised with these looooong blocks.

Comment: _"why many people don't support my feature request? "_ Because they don't think it's worth spending dev time to implement that.

Comment: Let them be "surprised". Users who get suspended for that long shouldn't be anyway.

Comment: @TechnicGoblin5R ATM of writing this comment it's 8 DVs, and 23 views.

Comment: Do you have an example where > 1 year ban for a user ended and they were suspended again for more than one year? You need to have lots of cases to make up for the development effort / time needed to implement this feature and be more useful then what currently is in place.

Comment: Well I use Gamepedia, a network of game wikis that uses Mediawiki as the software.  I already seen a case which an user from Gamepedia was blocked on the Russian-language Minecraft Wiki until year 2067, alongside its sockpuppet which was blocked indefinitely. I just checked the wiki's blocklist and the mentioned user is no longer blocked. The username of the Gamepedia blocked user was "Rusy233 ms", and the sockpuppet was similarly named "Rusy233 sm".

Comment: I wasn't asking for examples from other sites. I'm asking for examples of users within our community. We're not going to take precursory action because someone on the internet did something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 18):

While regular suspensions have a maximum duration of 1 year, a [network-wide suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/295232) can last longer than that.

> A network-wide suspension is applied to all network accounts of a user. It can only be issued by Stack Exchange employees and can be longer than 365 days.

Some users are banned for several years, some even until the 22nd century. That's pretty much 'indefinitely' in my book.

---

> Also add option to block the user's IP address to prevent new account registrations from the same person.

There is already a system in place which detects this and the suspension on the old account [automatically carries over to the new account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/295232).

> If the account holder creates a new account to bypass the suspension, that account will also be automatically suspended for the same reason until the end time of the original suspension, even if the old account was deleted.

Comment: But as I said in the coment to my own post, some people will be surprised with these very long blocks, so therefore, a better alternative would be changing the wording of 5+ year long blocks to "indefinite"?

Comment: I would be surprised if the block said 'indefinitely' and it turns out to be only 5 years ...

Answer (score 11):

As far as I'm concerned, too many users are already walking on eggshells, fully aware that their next cooling off period,  will probably last an entire year on MSE.

The site is already afflicted with uncertainty about its future, I  see no benefit, for anyone, exacerbating the current air of uncertainty and mistrust by handing out indefinite suspensions. Imagine sentencing someone by saying “One day, you'll be allowed to come back but you won't know when.” Simply awful.