# Arqade have reset my reputation. What shall I do?

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts

I've lost my reputation on Arqade Stack Exchange. When I went onto another Stack Exchange, it worked but when I went back, everything disappeared: the reputation, the badges, the questions and the answers. I've searched and I haven't found an answer. Can anybody give me an answer?

[image: Screenshot of a question attributed to a deleted user account.]

As you can see, it's replaced me with “user251621”

Comment: Have you searched Arqade itself to see if the questions and answers are still there, and what username is attached, if so could you [edit] to link one in in your question?

Comment: Your profile shows no posts on Arqade, so it's logical you're at a reputation of 1. Perhaps the posts are associated with a different account?

Comment: @Mast OP's profile also indicates that they haven't logged into their Arqade profile in two weeks.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "When I went onto another Stack Exchange," does that mean you visited a different SE  website using the ***same*** account? It is possible to set up more than one account, and it is possible that logging out and logging back changed something. You need to give more details.

Comment: I had 27 reputation and my question is replaced by something else

Comment: It looks like what's happened is that your original account was deleted, and the next time you logged into Arqade, it created a new one. I wouldn't have the first idea why your old account was deleted, but my assumption would be that you committed some kind of site violation, such as sockpuppeting (creating alternate accounts to vote for your own questions). If you really don't think you did anything that would have warranted account deletion, I can only suggest politely asking on [Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You better use the contact us form (link at the bottom of every page). On meta we can only speculate.

Comment: You have clarified very little. Did you use a different account when you left Arcade.SE (it's not against the rules to have more than one account, it's what you do with it/them that risks the wrath of SE, e.g. upvoting your own posts. However, if you were using the same account and just visited/participated on a different website that is something everyone does, every day. But some users go incognito. Some log out etc.... you need to provide details!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: For the reference, I voted to close as duplicate, not as off-topic.

Answer (score 12):

I'm a moderator over at Arqade, but I'm unable to get into the specifics here for privacy reasons. I've sent you a private message to your account over on Arqade.