# I am not able to join physics stack exchange through neither online nor app

Tags: support, bug

[image]

My question was removed earlier by Mr.Glorfindel
as it is a duplicate question.

So , actually there  is no other option i can join, then I need the solution .If others are able to join , there must be some way from your site or app, you can fix the bug.

The thing is , I am not able to join physics stack exchange from both online and through the app.
What is it that I should do ? I am reporting for this bug.

[image]

Comment: That's an error message from the app; it is known to have bugs like this. If you really have the same problem when visiting the site without using the app, **you should let us know what error you face there**. Preferably in your first question, so we can reopen it.

Comment: Well, the fix is not to use the app but a (mobile) browser. I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: To paraphrase a well-know saying: *screenshots or it didn't happen*. Note: I'm not angry at you or something; it's just that we can't help you unless you provide details.

Comment: It's tempting to try and "start over" when you get a suspension. I can understand. Luckily, SE is smarter than that. Thumbs down for playing the innocent victim though, and wasting our time.

Comment: Re: "join again", you have rejoined the site again, but as [your profile mentioned](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/284453/srijan-nahar), [wait until 14 November 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDNC.png) until the suspension over.

Comment: It's rude to completely change your question like that after you've already received and accepted an answer, because it invalidates that answer. If you want to ask something else, you'll need to post it as a separate question, although in the case of "can I join other SE sites while suspended from one", you can trivially answer that for yourself by just trying it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were suspended from the site when you deleted your profile previously. Because of that, creating a new profile would result in the suspension being reinstated. The API does not handle profile creation tasks that would have this result, and you are not allowed to recreate that profile through the API (which includes other options which utilize the API, such as the apps and the mobile site) until the original suspension ends.

If you are intent on recreating that suspended profile, you will have to visit the **full site** (use the link in the footer to switch out of mobile) in a browser and join the community that way. If that isn't working, you'll need to provide further details on what you're seeing when you try to do that.