# How do I stop getting red blob notifications for an answer that is CW and lost interest in?

Tags: support, notifications

Every time, and it's now getting bloody annoying, an edit is made to this answer I get a blob notification in the "Inbox" notification icon. The answer is Community Wiki, has been forever,  and has taken a life of it's own and I really have no more interest in it:

> [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean/125271#125271)

How can I turn this off? And if not can the devs add a feature to turn this off (at least for CW posts)?

Comment: Currently, I believe the only way to have this happen is to have the post [dissociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa).