# How many moderators are required to issue an account suspension?

Tags: support, moderation, account-suspension

E.g., can one moderator alone suspend a user account, or are at least 2, 3, etc. moderators required to issue an account suspension?

I read [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/178179) but don't see the answer there.

Answer (score 12):

Just one. One ♦ moderator can send a moderator message, including a suspension; other moderators will be 'CC-ed' because the message appears in their moderator inbox.

It's an old blog post, but the famous [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) uses the singular "the moderator" and it's still correct:

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in **timed suspension** for anywhere from 1 to 365 days.

Comment: Only Community Managers can issue suspensions longer than 365 days (I think they cap at 50 years). They are also capable of issuing them network-wide

Answer (score 12):

As a mod, I can do that all by myself!

But usually, we talk about these things before doing so, if at all possible. Especially for the longer suspensions, it's good to know you're not the only one considering doing this, and it's why you work in a team. It would be confusing to a user if I suspend them for a long period, but then the other mods decide I was out of line, and we'd have to unsuspend.