# Connecting to your deleted accounts

Tags: feature-request, support

A while back I deleted my account on one of the stackoverflow sites namely https://cs.stackexchange.com/ . At the time of deletion I was prompted that even after deletion of account, you can connect to the profile again.

Today I tried to login again and website created a new profile and connected all my accounts to my other stackoverflow accounts. Is there any way to connect to the lost profile with my current `damned` profile?

PS : The feature to delete your account should also be made more handy. Last time I needed to mail some admin as far as I remember.

Comment: You should have asked to disassociate your account from the rest, not delete it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not sure about this option. I don't remember being offered this choice.

Comment: Wait, you asked for a permanent deletion, *then* you want it undone, *and* you want deletion to be *easier*?

Comment: @balpha When I deleted, I got no option whether I want to disassociate my one account form the rest or whether I want to permanently delete it. If it would have showed me such suggestions with warnings, probably I would have given more thoughts to it. By showing such warning about losing data, one might change their mind :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your account data is hard-deleted, there is no simple way to restore all the account information, see [this post from Nick Craver for more detail:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115712/151385)

> On *deletion* (or destruction - user deletion + deleting posts, almost
>   always reserved for spammers) we nuke everything about the user, no
>   record just a line somewhere with a user ID in it, we don't even know
>   what your display name was, much less any private data (email, real
>   name, etc.)
>
> We've talked about recording this on delete/destroy in case a user
>   wants to come back, but we've punted on it until now for 2 reasons:
>
> - There are likely complications we don't realize until we get into implementing this (recording merges taught me this one)
> - We don't want the encourage the trigger-happy "delete me!" behavior in any way.
>
> That's not to say we won't do it to make even the exceptions easier on
>   us, at some point it's likely (just as merges finally became a
>   necessity) the pain of manually reversing both of these is a
>   nightmare, trust me.
>
> If you want to be deleted, that's fine by us - in most cases we're
>   sorry to see you go, but we'll respect your decision.  However, when
>   you ask for deletion do understand that **you're being deleted**, and
>   getting any data back is not always possible - and even if it is, it's
>   a total pain in the ass for us, and time *much* better spent on
>   improving the site for everyone.
>
> TL;DR version: don't *expect* your data to be restored (posts
>   associated, etc.) if you come back later, we simply don't have the
>   resources to keep doing that.

While SE might decide to spend the effort to manually reassociate your posts to your new account, they make no guarantee on that.