# Is there a way to only delete the chat profile?

Tags: support, chat, chat-profile

A user profile on the site can be deleted via [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) in the settings. Is there a way to delete only a chat profile? If the user can’t do it by himself/herself, can the moderators?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283431/how-does-one-delete-a-chat-profile I doubt if it is a very useful feature as I assume the chat account will be recreated once you visit chat again. Reading between the lines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153269/how-should-chat-user-and-content-removals-be-handled) I assume it is possible, if not for mods then for SE staff.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to delete your chat profile?

Comment: You're trying to break things arn't you? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek what is broken may never break.

Comment: @Ano my? I didn’t say about my profile. Just visit the link provided in the question. Which profile do you see? :-D

Comment: I misphrased that. I meant, why would one want to delete their own chat profile, in general?

Comment: @Ano I think the reason could be the same as for site profile deletion. Don’t know actually, just want to know about possibility of such action.

Comment: Moderators *may* be able to, but if you have more than a trivial amount of activity in chat or don't want your main-site profiles deleted then they'll probably need help. We don't really support deleting chat profiles without also deleting all relevant main-site profiles, but can sometimes oblige if contacted; I've updated the linked duplicate to note this.