# I want to delete my chat profile and anonymize my chats

Tags: support, chat, deleted-accounts

I want to delete my chat profile and anonymize all my chats. How do I do it? I read in other posts that it needs a manual intervention. How can I get someone to help me?

Comment: There’s a link at the bottom of the page saying “contact us”, or something similar. Use that and you can send a message to the team. Getting results might take a day or 5.

Comment: @Dan Thankyou for the information.

Comment: [Any mod can do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157511/152859), so you can ask any SE mod in chat. /cc @DanBron (No need for contact us form, unless more than 1000 messages which is unlikely)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the OP has over 1000 messages, according to their chat profile.

Comment: @rene oh. Oops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've hit the relevant buttons on your profile to put this in motion - both anonymization and deletion of your profile. Because you have a significant number of messages, I'm not able to perform those actions outright, but having hit the buttons has notified SE developers for confirmation of both.

You should also use the [contact form](/contact) to explain that you asked for this, so that SE has confirmation you want it to happen and I'm not just randomly deleting people.