# Chat entries from deleted users shouldn't be attributed to feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

[image]

Apparently one of the users on a chatroom I was in was deleted. He might have requested. It might be something else, it dosen't matter. What does matter is - well how it is handled is remarkably confusing. It is attributed to feeds, which is a generic name for the chat RSS feeds 'bot' where there's no dedicated 'user' for it.

*But* Feeds has a specific purpose, and its quite confusing, even when you have full context, to see chat entries from 'feeds' deleted, especially if the chatter in question was prolific.

Maybe community, anonymous or userNNNNNN attribution might make more sense

Comment: What was the date of that message? And, can you check again?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/64079218/history is the message, does say anon now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was due to a minor error in the deletion process. Specifically, when a user is removed:

- For many data elements we perform a soft delete (put a non-`NULL` value in a `DeletedDate` column).
- For some data elements, we update several other columns also, and for the user ID column we *sometimes* assign the `Feeds` user id (`-2`).
- This logic was erroneously copied to the process for the `Messages` table, which *should have* had the user ID set to `NULL`. (We *did* update the display name of those messages to `anon`, but the display name associated with the user - when a user ID is present - overrides in the UI.)

I've set the affected rows to have a user ID of `NULL` and corrected the logic in the deletion process.

Comment: So your last bullet is why when a moderator uses the "anonymize messages" tool, it won't remove the user ID from the messages, and that's why if a user isn't OK with that, the mod has to reach out to SE staff to do the needful (null the user IDs on the messages)?

Comment: @Sonic I'd have to get a moderator to comment on that, I'm not familiar with that tool / process. A lot of what I know about chat I've learned... today.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: When in doubt, ask balpha. ;)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Moderators don't have access to anonymizing messages, that's a tool available to a subset of employees.

Comment: @AdamLear Per [this prior post of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157511/377214), this tool was at one point available to moderators. A chat moderator also [confirmed just now](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9601544#9601544) that they do still have the ability. Perhaps you were looking at a chat user with 1,000+ messages?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Huh, I forgot about that one. Fun fact: there are two anonymization tools. The employee-only one is similar to the mod one, but it fully anonymizes usernames ("anonymous" rather than "userXXXX"), and mods can only anonymize profiles with less than 1000 messages.

Comment: @Adam welcome to the world of Sonic, the man who never forget any tiny bit of detail about Stack Exchange.