# Is Community♦ more eagerly auto-deleting than it should?

Tags: bug, auto-delete

Today, Community♦ deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873467/prime-number-generator-in-c). (10K only, obviously)

That's good, if you wonder. The question didn't add any value to the site.

But, as far as I could determine (my search-fu is weak, so I may have missed something), it doesn't meet [the new criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/177145) for auto-deletion,

- Closed more than 7 days ago

Yes, that.

- Not closed as a duplicate

That too.

- Score <= 0

And that.

- Not locked

Also this.

- No answers with a score > 0

But not this!

- No accepted answer
- No pending reopen votes
- No edits to the body or title of the question in the past 7 days

nor [the old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/177145).

Having Community♦ auto-delete closed questions with negative score, but upvoted answers risks losing valuable content, so such questions should be brought to the attention of moderators/high-rep users to determine whether they should be deleted or kept.

Did Community♦ go past its duty, or have I missed something?

Comment: Is the OP still around?

Comment: This is how it begins.

Comment: Hard to tell whether it was deleted by the usual cleanup, or from the owner deletion.

Comment: @Rory: We're approaching singularity!

Comment: @Rory http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2013-03-29/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The owner has been deleted.

Negatively-scored questions by users that have since been deleted get auto-cleaned too.

Comment: Regardless of having upvoted answers? (Can you link to the relevant criteria?)

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin': Regardless of upvoted answers; I've often detected these because I lost upvotes.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin': Criteria: [Difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/88996#88996)

Comment: Hmm, I don't like that. Most of the time nothing of value is lost, but there's the risk.