# What causes Community to destroy non RA or spam-flagged questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

On Politics, a troll used to like to spam some weird question about urbanization and homicide in South America or some similar incoherent nonsense. Looking through some deleted questions in moderation tools, I found [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46960/24826) (2K on Politics) by the troll.

It was not flagged rude/abusive or spam—it isn’t hidden in the revision history—but it was deleted by community five minutes after it was posted. The user was destroyed.

[image: A screenshot of its timeline:it was asked, review in first posts, and deleted when the user was destroyed]

**What causes Community to delete non-rude/abusive or spam-flagged posts?**

Comment: Did the troll have their account deleted? (Might mess with the displayed username of the deleter)

Comment: @Jenayah Oh! I forgot! [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc6t3.png) is a screenshot of the timeline.

Comment: Well, looks like the timeline answers this question? That user got "destroyed" (I guess due to a mod deleting the user after the spam questions) and this question was deleted as well. Since it might not have received any spam flags, it was just "normally" deleted.

Comment: @Tom Ok, maybe I should self-answer? I understand what happened now.

Comment: @WeareMonica. for FAQ; this is surely not a unique question that I had of why Community would delete a post like this.

Comment: Well, I wrote that as a comment, because I guessed that (although it makes sense), but I would wait for an answer of someone who definitely knows that. But you still can self-answer if you like.

Comment: @Tom looking at other posts that is definitely right. written an answer.

Comment: What is "RA"? (It is not in [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353).)

Comment: @Peter rude or abusive

Comment: From the title, this seems like a valid question. In fact, I believe that the answer is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink Could you explain why the question was deleted?

Comment: @Iamnotthewayyouspeak the same person was repeatedly spamming this weird viewpoint in questions from different accounts.

Comment: I see, but how is well-known behavioral research a weird viewpoint? Maybe the spamming was caused by closing a valid question?

Comment: @Iamnotthewayyouspeak the apparently same user kept spamming these weird, almost identical non-answers to questions from different then-destroyed accounts, then asking these unintelligible questions. Also the whole content of the question was a map and "Seems like a compelling reason. Maybe something there"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When an account is destroyed (distinct from deleted) by a moderator, all of its posts get deleted.

From [an answer by Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/399694):

> "Destroyed" users...have all of their posts deleted. It is intended for things like spammers, where we just want them to be gone. A user must have less than 500 reputation in order to be destroyed. Given that, it's up to the moderator to simply select "destroy" from the mod menu.

Comment: @tchrist I used “it” to specify it is the user *account*, not the person, that is destroyed.