# Automatic deletion of downvoted answers when associated user account is deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, down-votes, deleted-answers, deleted-accounts

According to [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s comment on the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78629/does-deleting-an-account-delete-the-associated-posts-and-comments), a regular delete of an account also deletes anything that is negatively voted.  However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364505/how-do-you-submit-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc) has two answers from deleted accounts that are downvoted but not deleted.

How does that happen?  Is it a bug?  Or were the downvotes accumulated after the accounts were deleted?  And if it was after they were deleted, is there any mechanism for auto-deleting those negative posts (perhaps 7 days after it gets negatively voted)...or should there be?  Or should I just flag those for moderator deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/364505/timeline) those posts did not receive their first downvotes until Dec 22 '09, about a year *after* they were first posted. I see two possibilities here:

- Their account deletion predates those first downvotes.
- <strike>Their account deletion predates the auto-deletion script and their answers survived because of that.</strike> -- Sklivvz [discounted this option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199955).

In any case, I've voted to delete both, they do not add anything useful.

Negatively voted *answers* are generally not auto-deleted (so outside of the deleted account mechanism), so I don't think there is any auto-deletion for answers downvoted after the owner has been deleted.

These two posts were otherwise ripe for flagging. One was a reply from the original question asker, so Not An Answer applies there, the other post a link-only answer with a dead link. A moderator would have deleted both had you flagged them, for those reasons alone.

Both posts have now been deleted without moderator intervention, each received 3 deletion votes by higher-rep users.

Comment: Quick poll: do you routinely cast delete votes on obvious non-answers together with your flags?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: No, I don't. I thought to flag first, then realized that just deleting would probably have been a better idea. :-P

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: It's a holdover from too much reviewing in queues on sites where I don't yet have the privilege to cast delete votes.

Comment: That's OK. I was asking out of curiosity. There are certain users who I trust have good enough judgment to figure out how to exercise the delete privilege effectively, but the problem is it's incredibly difficult to trust a user to do so especially when the privilege is based on rep alone.

Answer (score 2):

The "delete nukes negatively scored posts" dates back to Sept. 18th, 2008 and as such the user must have been deleted when the posts were at 0 score, sometime between Dec '08 and Dec '09.

The down votes must have been cast after the user was deleted.